# Auto number and reset count for each different column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to figure out how I can reset the row numbering in mysql for each different value in a given column. Probably best explained with an example:

I have a set of users who make client visits, each client may be visited more than once and my table records the date the visit was made (but not whether this was the first,second,third etc visit). So my table looks like:

```
clientid   visitdate
100        10-apr-2012
101        15-apr-2012
101        25-apr-2012
102        26-apr-2012
100        28-apr-2012
```

What I'm looking to find out is how many (e.g.) second visits were made  for a given date period. So in the data above, there are 3 first visits and 2 second visits.

I'm assuming I need to use something like the @rownum functionality, like this:

SELECT visitdate, clientid @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row from visit, (SELECT @rownum := 0) a
ORDER BY clientid,visitdate

which gives me:

```
clientid   visitdate     row
100        10-apr-2012   1
100        28-apr-2012   2
101        15-apr-2012   3
101        25-apr-2012   4
102        26-apr-2012   5
```

but what I'm really looking for is:

```
clientid   visitdate     row
100        10-apr-2012   1
100        28-apr-2012   2
101        15-apr-2012   1
101        25-apr-2012   2
102        26-apr-2012   1
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to reset the row counter for each clientid.

Perhaps I'm approaching this in the wrong way, and I can do these calculations in the application (PHP) code, but it feels like something that should be achievable within the db.

I've seen approaches for SQLServer (eg: http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/74891/Auto-number-and-reset-based-on-data-value-in-a), but doesn't seem this works for mysql?

Any help/suggestions much appreciated,
Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
IF(@prev != a.clientid, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, @prev:=a.clientid, a.*
FROM (
SELECT 
visitdate, 
clientid 
FROM visit, (SELECT @rownum := 0, @prev:='') sq
ORDER BY clientid,visitdate
) a
```

And btw, there is no "@rownum functionality", it's just some selfmade "solution", @rownum is just a variable. You could as well name it @whatever.

Comment: Perfect, didn't know @prev