# mysql row numbering reset every different record values

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is pretty similar to this one [Auto number and reset count for each different column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754812/auto-number-and-reset-count-for-each-different-column-value)

except that I can't make it work.

```
I have the table record:
ID(autoINC) plate_number
1                A
2                A 
3                A
4                B
5                B
6                C
7                C
```

I want to display something like this adding additional field cc:

```
I have the table record:
ID(autoINC) plate_number count
1                A         1
2                A         2 
3                A         3
4                B         1
5                B         2
6                C         1
7                C         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a correlated subquery which sequentially count the row which can be used as a  rownumber.

```
SELECT  A.ID, 
        A.plate_number, 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    tableName c
            WHERE   c.plate_number = a.plate_number AND
                    c.ID <= a.ID) AS RowNumber
FROM    TableName a
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74d38/1)