# SQL create table with numbering reset every different record values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to create a table like this:

[image]

in SQL Server 2012

For every different REF_NUMBER create new sequence for column AA.

I have read [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375564/mysql-row-numbering-reset-every-different-record-values), but I don't want to do in insert statement

My idea is to create a function that read the previous AA for a ref_number and return the next AA, but I looking for more efficient solution. 
Any idea?

Comment: why do you want to get it in advance, as something else could add a row while you're not looking at then you dont have the right number any more

Comment: How are you sorting? Do you have another column?

Comment: Yes I have a column date that I can sort rows

Answer (score 1):

Using this query with `row_number()` window function should give you the output you are looking for.

```
select ref_number, 
       row_number() over (partition by ref_number order by [date]) as AA
  from myTable;
```

Comment: The Other Option is to do it off a checksum if you need to use Multiple Columns.